# Netbeans 8.02: An Instance of the program already running

Tags: java, netbeans

Suddenly I have started getting this error.
It was working fine as expected until recently for months without any issue.

The problem I am facing is when I am opening file associated with Netbeans using double click, on 1st instance it opens fine but while opening the second file using double click.
I get a window telling:

```
An instance of the program is already running with your user directory
Either a previous session of the program is running on a different computer
and using the same user directory.

If another session of program is running with the same user 
directory,please click to cancel to prevent the corruption of the user
directory. If you are sure that no other instances of the program is running
with your user directory, click OK to continue.
```

I have google for error. The only solution I found is that there is lock file in your user directory which needs to be deleted.

But in my case what I observed that there is no stale lock file. The lock is present only when Netbeans is running. once I close the netbeans, the lock file is removed on its own.

I have also deleted all the cache, thinking that it might be causing some issues.
But none of it could resolve the issue.

Again If I directly starts Netbeans without double clicking the file, then I am not able to open even a single file using double click and I get the same error box.

Comment: you get this comment when you attempt to compile the program?

Comment: No. I get this when trying to open a file from file explorer by double clicking which is associated with netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is late to write but i have had exactly the same problem. So many times i uninstalled and installed old version (like 7.x) , even i uninstalled java jdk :)

I thought to start using JetBrains but i couldnt open the JetBrains. I searched why JetBrains doesnt open for a few hours and i realized that the problem is Kaspersky.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206489659-Error-Cannot-Lock-System-Folders

I uninstalled Kaspersky and opened the JetBrains.

Bingo! :)

And with that NetBeans (8.2) started to open without any problem.

I have no idea why Kaspersky would be a problem.

(Platform: Win 10 , x64)